Groups within group on qgis2web
I have several layers of polygons, each have defined symbologies. I want to make some layers merged into one group and then put it as a subgroup in another group.

Now when I export this on qgis2web using openlayers or leaflet, the subgroup separates with the group.
Any way I can maintain the groupings on export?
Maybe it has settings in the qgis2web plugin?
Or maybe I can code it in the JS file?

As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Yes, I haven't yet programmed the management of nested groups.
At the bottom of the index.html file add a <script></script> before closing the </body> and override the layersList variable like this:
<script>
        var layersList = [
        new ol.layer.Group({
                    title: 'Basemap',
                    openInLayerSwitcher: true,      
                    layers: [
                    
            new ol.layer.Group({
                            title: 'Rischio Sismico',
                            openInLayerSwitcher: false,
                            layers: [
                lyr_FaglieattiveecapaciITHACA_MicrozonazioneSismica,lyr_Zonediattenzioneperinstabilit_MicrozonazioneSismica
                ]}),    
            new ol.layer.Group({
                            title: 'Rischio Incendi',
                            openInLayerSwitcher: false,
                            layers: [
                lyr_Pericolositareeperimetrali,lyr_Pericolositareediinterfaccia,lyr_Cancelli_incendi
                ]}),
            new ol.layer.Group({
                            title: 'Rischio Diga',
                            openInLayerSwitcher: false,
                            layers: [
                lyr_Viabilitdacontrollareregolamentare_diga,lyr_Limiterischiocollassodiga_modificatosubasegeomorfologica,lyr_Arearischiocollassodiga,lyr_Cancelli_diga
                ]}),
                
             lyr_GoogleSatellite,
        ]}),
        new ol.layer.Group({
                    title: 'Cartografia generale',
                    openInLayerSwitcher: true,
                    layers: [
        lyr_Idrografia,lyr_ComuniLimitrofi,lyr_Confini,
        ]}),
        new ol.layer.Group({
                    title: 'Toponomastica',
                    openInLayerSwitcher: true,
                    layers: [
        lyr_Edifici,lyr_Stradario,lyr_Civici,
        ]}),
        
        ];
</script>
</body>

Here you can insert groups inside other groups.
Warning: you must acquire the names of the lyrs from the layers.js file and, unfortunately, they will change if you add layers as they have a final progressive numbering.
So let's say that this method is only suitable if you have a fairly static project where the layers do not change frequently.

I tried this code and used the layers.js to replace the names of the layers. It didn't work. I put the code between the last  and the . Should I edit in any other place?

the place is right, surely he writes something wrong. Can you upload your project somewhere and link it here?
